# How to integrate 2.5% sales fee in an NFT Marketplace

Tags: contract-development, nodejs, nft, fees

I'm currenttly building an NFT marketplace, I am done with all the major functionalities, i.e listing, selling, buying etc. but the problem is, when wiriting the code earlier I used a fixed listing fee of 0.1 ether and now I would like to integrate a 2.5% fee on every sale

Here's my solidity code

```
function createMarketSale(address nftContract, uint256 itemId, uint256 commission)  
 public  
 payable  
 nonReentrant  
    {  
        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;  
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;  
 require(  
 msg.value == price,  
 "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"  
        );  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);  
 IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;  
        _itemsSold.increment();  
 payable(owner).transfer(commission);  
    }
```

Here's How my web3 frontend interacts with the contract

```
async function buyNFT() {
 const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
 const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);

 const signer = provider.getSigner();
 const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer);

 const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), "ether");
 const fee = +((2.5 / 100) * nft.price);
 let commission = fee.toString();

 let transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nftaddress, nft.itemId, commission, {
 value: price,
 });

 await transaction.wait();
    window.location.replace("/profile");
 }
```

but I keep getting an Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute when it gets to this line :

```
 payable(owner).transfer(commission);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one major issue with your project - you should move the fee logic inside the smart contract and remove it from the front end part. In the current logic malicious users can skip using the dApp and interact directly with the smart contract and by doing this they can set the fee to whatever they want. I will use the `SafeMath` contract provided from OpenZeppelin to build you a sample fee method where fee will be extracted directly from what's been passed to the method as value ( from the `msg.value` ):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, with an overflow flag.
     *
     * _Available since v3.4._
     */
    function tryAdd(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 c = a + b;
            if (c < a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the substraction of two unsigned integers, with an overflow flag.
     *
     * _Available since v3.4._
     */
    function trySub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b > a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a - b);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, with an overflow flag.
     *
     * _Available since v3.4._
     */
    function tryMul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
            // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
            // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
            if (a == 0) return (true, 0);
            uint256 c = a * b;
            if (c / a != b) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the division of two unsigned integers, with a division by zero flag.
     *
     * _Available since v3.4._
     */
    function tryDiv(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a / b);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers, with a division by zero flag.
     *
     * _Available since v3.4._
     */
    function tryMod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a % b);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Addition cannot overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a - b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a * b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a / b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * reverting when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a % b;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting with custom message on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * CAUTION: This function is deprecated because it requires allocating memory for the error
     * message unnecessarily. For custom revert reasons use {trySub}.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b <= a, errorMessage);
            return a - b;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers, reverting with custom message on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a / b;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * reverting with custom message when dividing by zero.
     *
     * CAUTION: This function is deprecated because it requires allocating memory for the error
     * message unnecessarily. For custom revert reasons use {tryMod}.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a % b;
        }
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    function calculateFee(uint256 _num) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 onePercentofTokens = _num.mul(100).div(100 * 10 ** uint256(2));
        uint256 twoPercentOfTokens = onePercentofTokens.mul(2);
        uint256 halfPercentOfTokens = onePercentofTokens.div(2);
        return twoPercentOfTokens + halfPercentOfTokens;
    }

    function createMarketSale() public payable {
        // logic, logic, logic
        uint256 extractFee = this.calculateFee(msg.value);
        // logic, logic, logic
    }
}
```

Unfortunately solidity is very primitive when it comes to make calculation with floats, so you need workarounds as what I did in method `calculateFee`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but the problem is I'm still getting that error when trying to transfer the extractFee to the contract owner; I'm getting Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute, any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Look at my code here https://pastebin.com/DHBzh9eM , I added ```payable(owner).transfer(extractFee);``` right after the fee calculation and it's working well.